# Issues in reading of data from text file Android Development

Tags: android

i have been experiencing problem reading data from text files which resides in my internal storage of my mobile phone. My code is as below:

```
   public void recommend(View view) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String filename = "SendLog.txt";
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView134);
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
                tv.getText();
                tv.setText(line);
            }
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm not getting any data input to my mobile phone. My "SendLog.txt" file reside in /storage/emulated/0/SendLog.txt directory. Anyone can assist me? I want to read everything from the text file and display in textView134. Anyone can assist?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you getting any warnings in logcat? If so, post them.

Comment: hi, there no warnings in logcat

Comment: Are you sure the FileInputStream is pointing to the correct file because you did not specify a path in the filename String? You should also be checking that the file exists before trying to open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"/storage/emulated/0/SendLog.txt" is located on the External Storage, not the internal.

Instead of context.openFileInput(filename) you should be using Environment.getExtenalStorageDirectory() for example,

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getExtenalStorageDirectory(), filename));
```

Though you will need to handle possibilities such as the External Storage being unavailable / unmounted.

You will also need the manifest permission to read external storage, or alternately to write it if you plan to do that as well (you only need one of the two, as write implies read).

Comment: i do not have external sd card mounted on my phone. It should be in the internal storage?

Comment: You have a wrong concept of the storage possibilities under Android. Every device has internal and external storage. And if you add an sd card then the device has removable storage. External storage has nothing to do with a -removable- sd card.

Comment: Its true that external storage does not necessarily have anything to do with an sd card.  However, it is not true that external storage is necessarily available on a given device at the time your app is running on it.  Nonetheless, your stated path is one which refers to an external storage of some type, and so it should be accessed with an external storage API, not the internal storage API your tried to use in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are building a string using stringbuilder but instead are settexting line. The result is last line in file, which may be an empty line

Comment: hi, do you mean set text?

Comment: Yes. Settext(line) repeatedly will only show last line read. First stringbuild and after looping settext sb.toString()